# PC not connecting to monitor. Windows 10 not booting correctly?

Tags: windows-10, boot

I'll keep only the details.

I have tried to connect four seperate monitors, all show no connection after trying for a few seconds. Tried changing cable too.
After turning the computer on, no matter how long I wait, pressing the on button again turns the computer off instantly, indicating it is maybe not even booting. (Usually it will take a few seconds as it prepares to shut down)

I had this same issue once in the past a few months ago, but it fixed itself after a few hours of being off. But not this time.

Any suggestions on what the problem could be aside from a broken video card?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you even get into the BIOS?  Is this a laptop?

Comment: Try installing a speaker and getting the beep codes if you get no display at all

Comment: No beeps, can't see screen at all